# Accessing Recently Added Data From Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

I am adding content to a FireStore database and I want to access recently added content without creating a "Recently Added" collection inside the database, and populate it into a Chrome Extension Popup UI. Is there a way I can access recently added content from a database and populate it into the UI without making another FireStore collection? (because that's expensive)

Is using Chrome Local Storage a viable option, or is there some other free way do do this?

Comment: What if you change your item schema to have a dateAdded timestamp then query for the data by dateAdded descending and limit to however much data you need?

Comment: That would actually be a good idea. I didn't think about that. Thank you @RhettHarrison

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to mention that the content is inside an array. So I would need to go through that array and find the most recently added thing. Would the same concept still apply

Comment: What comes to mind is doing a "batch update" in firestore. Essentially you can update multiple documents in one call. It is a little trickier, but firestore has the docs for it. I would think of calling the whole collection in your case, updating what you need, then pushing the updated collection. But I may not be understanding the whole situation

Comment: Do you mean when you query for multiple firestore documents you get an array? Or the document itself is an array?

Comment: The document field that I'm trying to query is an array @RhettHarrison

Comment: Since you would be querying for multiple documents that are type array, I think it will return an array of arrays. I don't think this is going to change anything for you though. On the document you will have a field that is type array and then another field of timestamp for recently added